# Devops pipelines - checkout code from other repo: auth error

Tags: git, azure, devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I want to add a repo to my pipeline by writing

checkout: git://Utility/Utility

But I get an auth Error:

### [warning]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 1.477 seconds before retry.

- I added the service that has to check out the code to the Repo Admin

  - the projects are placed under the same organization

But what do i miss?

Comment: Did you check the project settings ? project settings --> Version Control and made sure that this repo is included ?

Comment: @rootkonda: Do you mean importing the repo ? How do I include a repo that is placed under the same organization?

Answer (score 0):

For this issue ,it could be caused by the change in permission settings in Version Control.
You can go to the project settings --> Repos --> selected Git repositories on the left and  make sure to include `Project Collection Build Service(project)` under Users. You can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51547858/vsts-git-fetch-failed-with-exit-code-128) for the similar issue.

[image]

If the above not work, I need some information for further investigation:
Which agent do you use? If you use private agent, please try to select clean source directory in your build definition and then queue the build agent by private agent. Also, please try to set System.Debug variable to true in build definition, then queue build and post the detail log here.

Comment: I have 2 projects with repositories that should be included in this pipeline. To both I added the build service of this pipeline as a user. An hosted agent is used here. ##[debug]
#[debug]  Arguments: '-c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin'
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier IntegrationUtility does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository 'https://XXX.visualstudio.com/IntegrationUtility/_git/IntegrationUtility/' not found

Comment: Please check if your access level is Stakehoder,if so, try to set "Basic" access.

Comment: @klangecht Would you please share your latest information about this issue?